# Use apache mod_mem_cache to cache Rest services

Tags: apache, rest, wildcard, mod-cache

Behind Apache 2.2 httpd server, i have a java REST-based application with this kind of service :

```
GET /countries/canada
```

I'd like to enable **mod_mem_cache** to speed up these services like that :

```
CacheEnable mem /countries/*
```

Is it possible to use wildcard ?
If not, what is there any solution to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, we don't need wildcard.

For example, if a defined the following configuration :

```
ProxyPass /jsontest/  http://echo.jsontest.com/
ProxyPassReverse /jsontest/  http://echo.jsontest.com/
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
    <IfModule mod_mem_cache.c>
        CacheEnable mem /jsontest/
        CacheDefaultExpire 300 
        MCacheSize 1024000 
        MCacheMaxObjectCount 10000 
        MCacheMinObjectSize 1 
        MCacheMaxObjectSize 2048000 
        CacheStorePrivate On
        CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On 
        CacheStoreNoStore On
        CacheIgnoreCacheControl On
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I can request :

```
http://localhost/jsontest/
```

or

```
http://localhost/jsontest/titi/tutu
```

and apache will store each response and serve them :

```
Incoming request is asking for an uncached version of /jsontest/, but we have been configured to ignore it and serve cached content anyway
mem_cache: Cached url: http://localhost:80/jsontest/?

Incoming request is asking for an uncached version of /jsontest/, but we have been configured to ignore it and serve cached content anyway
mod_cache.c(312): cache: serving /jsontest/

Incoming request is asking for an uncached version of /jsontest/titi/tutu, but we have been configured to ignore it and serve cached content anyway
mod_cache.c(753): cache: Caching url: /jsontest/titi/tutu

Incoming request is asking for an uncached version of /jsontest/titi/tutu, but we have been configured to ignore it and serve cached content anyway
mod_cache.c(312): cache: serving /jsontest/titi/tutu
```

**Be carefull :**

With CacheStorePrivate, CacheIgnoreNoLastMod, CacheStoreNoStore  and CacheIgnoreCacheControl, i disabled all default behavior and force cache !!!
You have to ask yourself if it is your requirement.